# Sorting Program getting weird anomalies

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file

(sorry that everything is in code form, stack overflow wouldn't let me submit for reason)

I have recently been interested in computer sorting, and attempted to write a simple batch numerical sorter. It uses very basic math and is extremely inefficient, but was mostly a learning experience. The program almost works with certain number sets. I am relatively new to batch, so as far as I can tell, there is nothing specifically wrong with my sorting and checking, yet I've experiencing quite a few anomalies after sorts. In a set of 10 values, it sorts perfectly, except the largest number ends up being put first. And in larger sets of numbers, for example:

```
> Values:10
> 
> Random Maximum:10
> 
> UNSORTED: 8 5  0  0  5  4  7  1  5  1 
>
> SORTED: 8  0  1  1  4  5  5  5  7
```

The following are the anomalies I have so far experienced while debugging:

- Highest number put first
- Numbers of lower places(tens, hundreds, etc) placed randomly in sets with a majority of numbers with a higher case
- Some numbers removed from unsorted-sorted
- Sorting restarts at various points in some cases in sorted.txt
- Likely many more to be discovered

Here is my batch script so far:

```
@echo off
color b
title sorting
if exist sortedlist.txt del sortedlist.txt
if exist unsortedlist.txt del unsortedlist.txt
if exist log.txt del log.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ar=0
set num=0
set check=0
set checknum=0
set checks=0
set /P totalnumber="Values:"
set /P randmax="Max Random Value:"
cls
::set totalnumber=200
::set randmax=500
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM INITIATED
echo VALUES:%totalnumber%
echo RANDMAX:%randmax%
echo %date% : %time% >> log.txt
echo PROGRAM INITIATED >> log.txt
echo VALUES:%totalnumber% >> log.txt
echo RANDMAX:%randmax% >> log.txt
:array
if %num% LSS %totalnumber% (
set /A a[%num%]=%random% %% %randmax%
set /A num=%num%+1
goto array
)
if %num% EQU %totalnumber% (
echo %DATE%:%TIME%
echo VALUE GEN COMPLETE
echo %date%:%time% >> log.txt
echo VALUE GEN COMPLETE >> log.txt
goto echo1
)
:echo1
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set a[') do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set a[') do echo %%s >> unsortedlist.txt
echo sort initialized
goto sort
)
:sort
set sorts=0
set n=0
:sortloop
set /A m=%n%+1
if %n% EQU %totalnumber% (
echo %date% : %time%
echo SORT COMPLETED
echo SORTS : %sorts%
echo %date% : %time% >> log.txt
echo SORT COMPLETED >> log.txt
echo SORTS : %sorts% >> log.txt
goto check
)
if !a[%n%]! GTR !a[%m%]! (
set hold=!a[%m%]!
set a[%m%]=!a[%n%]!
set a[%n%]=%hold%
set /A n=%n%+1
set /A sorts=%sorts%+1
goto sortloop
)
if !a[%n%]! LSS !a[%m%]! (
set /A n=%n%+1
goto sortloop
)
if !a[%n%]! EQU !a[%m%]! (
set /A n=%n%+1
goto sortloop
)
pause
:check
set check=0
set checknum=0
set checks=0
:checkloop
set /A checknumplus=%checknum%+1
if %check% EQU %totalnumber% (
goto complete
)
if %checknum% EQU %totalnumber% (
set /A checks=%checks%+1
echo %date% : %time%
echo CORRECT PAIRS : %check%
echo CHECKS : %checks% 
echo %date% : %time% >> log.txt
echo CORRECT PAIRS : %check% >> log.txt
echo CHECKS : %checks% >> log.txt
goto sort
)
if !a[%checknum%]! LSS !a[%checknumplus%]! (
set /A check=%check%+1
set /A checknum=%checknum%+1
goto checkloop
)
if !a[%checknum%]! GTR !a[%checknumplus%]! (
set /A checknum=%checknum%+1
goto checkloop
)
if !a[%checknum%]! EQU !a[%checknumplus%]! (
set /A check=%check%+1
set /A checknum=%checknum%+1
goto checkloop
)
pause
:complete
set a[%totalnumber%+1]=%a[0]%
set %a[0]%=0
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM COMPLETE
echo %date% : %time% >> log.txt
echo PROGRAM COMPLETE >> log.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set a[') do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set a[') do echo %%s >> sortedlist.txt
```

Any help cleaning up code, adding code, or resolving any of the issues I have will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could initialize the vars far easier with set /A `set /A ar=num=check=checknum=checks=0`. Use proper indentation for the code blocks. Use a for /l to fill your pseudo array.

Comment: @LotPings sorry I am not very advanced in batch, could you specify what you mean by using /I for my pseudo code array. Also do you think doing this would remediate the issues I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

This question in "interesting". Independently of your low knowledge in Batch files, you have not asked a single definite question about the posted code! You basically have invited us to do whatever we want with it, so that is what I did. Also, it is important to note that the supposed "output example" show in the question have no relation with the posted code...

**EDIT**: The method used to show the list of numbers in a single line use a variable, so the maximum number of results is limited by the maximum variable length. For example, with numbers of 4 digits each the list can contain a maximum of 1637 numbers that, IMHO, was enough for a "simple batch numerical sorter" program.

I modified the method used to show the results, so it now supports 10,000 random numbers or more. However, you should note that this sorting method is *slow*, so I suggest to insert an `echo` command in the sortLoop in order to know that the program is still running.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

color b
title sorting

set /P "totalNumber=Values:"
set /P "randMax=Max Random Value:"
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM INITIATED
echo VALUES:%totalNumber%
echo randMax:%randMax%

(
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM INITIATED
echo VALUES:%totalNumber%
echo randMax:%randMax%
) > log.txt

:array
for /L %%i in (1,1,%totalNumber%) do set /A a[%%i]=!random! %% randMax

echo %DATE%:%TIME%
echo VALUE GEN COMPLETE
(
echo %date%:%time%
echo VALUE GEN COMPLETE
) >> log.txt

echo/
< NUL (
set /P "=UNSORTED: "
for /L %%i in (1,1,%totalNumber%) do set /P "=!a[%%i]! "
)
echo/
echo/
echo sort initialized

set "sorts=0"
:sortLoop
set "hold="
for /L %%m in (2,1,%totalNumber%) do (
   set /A n=%%m-1
   for %%n in (!n!) do if !a[%%n]! GTR !a[%%m]! (
      set /A hold=a[%%m], a[%%m]=a[%%n], a[%%n]=hold, sorts+=1
   )
)
REM ECHO Sorts: %sorts%
if defined hold goto sortLoop

echo %date% : %time%
echo SORT COMPLETED
echo SORTS : %sorts%
(
echo %date% : %time%
echo SORT COMPLETED
echo SORTS : %sorts%
) >> log.txt


:complete
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM COMPLETE
(
echo %date% : %time%
echo PROGRAM COMPLETE
) >> log.txt

echo/
< NUL (
set /P "=SORTED:   "
for /L %%i in (1,1,%totalNumber%) do set /P "=!a[%%i]! "
)
echo/
```

**EDIT**: *New sorting method added*

I originally thought that this program represents to you "mostly a learning experience in computer sorting". However, if you are interested in create two files with random numbers named `sorted.txt` and `unsorted.txt` in an efficient way, you may use this code instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "totalNumber=Values:"
set /P "randMax=Max Random Value:"

echo/
set /P "=UNSORTED: " < NUL
< NUL (for /L %%i in (1,1,%totalNumber%) do (
   set /A a=!random! %% randMax
   set /P "=!a! " > CON
   set "a=    !a!"
   echo !a:~-5!
)) > unsorted.txt
echo/

sort unsorted.txt /O sorted.txt

echo/
< NUL (
set /P "=SORTED:   "
for /F %%a in (sorted.txt) do set /P "=%%a "
)
echo/
```

Remember that the maximum random number is 32767, but the amount of numbers have no limit.

Comment: My question does seem very ambiguous, and not a specific question, and that is because I don't even know what to ask, I was receiving these results, and had absolutely no idea what could be the cause of this. I spent some time attempting to debug and look into the issue, yet I found nothing that would help in this situation. I was essentially asking if anybody knew what I did wrong. Also the data set associated is the result of the program when tested with 10 values, and a max random value of 10, it shows one of the errors of the code.

Comment: The cause of your error is this: in the sort process you manage each array element by its subscript, but when you show the result you use the order of `set` command, that is _alphabetic_! Just define `set a[1]=1` and `set a[10]=1` and type `set a[` to check this point.

Comment: This program seems to be also encountering some of the errors I was getting, in terms of number in lower places values being seemingly randomly inserted at various points in the code, also when I put in large values, it seems to crash

Comment: Please, post here an output example of the wrong result and _explain_ why such a result is wrong. Sorry, but I don't understand what _"number in lower places values being seemingly randomly inserted at various points in the code"_ means. Any number may be inserted at any place. If you are talking about a _new requirement_ that don't appear in the original description, then you must edit your question and carefully describe this new specification.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but from some basic testing the flaw appears to be getting the error, I'm not sure the cause, but an example of the error would be in a sorted set "1 4 8 10 39 283 1938 38 9348 10294". This was a major issue in my original program, seemingly not in yours though. Yet your program still does crash when larger values are entered for amount of values to sort.

Comment: This code works and is exactly what the goal of my original program was, thanks you for all the help. One last note is that I don't understand exactly how this program is doing the sorting, or how it is creating the values, or checking to make sure the sorting is correct... pretty much the whole thing. It has worked perfectly and gone very fast through all of my tests so far.

Comment: May I ask you to select (check-mark) this answer and also upvote it?

Comment: After reviewing this again, I noticed you are using the sort command, which automatically sorts using built in algorithms. The point of this program was to provide functionality, yet act as a learning experience for me to advance in my batch coding skills, and learn more about the actual functionality and mathematics of these sorting algorithms.

Comment: Well, the first code uses your original BubbleSort algorithm and it should correctly run with 10000 numbers now, after I modified the method used to show the result. Did you tested it?

Comment: I just tested the first code with 10000 for both Values and MaxRandom. In my computer the program took 52 seconds to generate the 10000 random numbers and start the sorting loop, and then took 3 minutes and 48 seconds to complete _the first pass_ of the BubbleSort algorithm and show `Sorts: 9992`. When you run this program with large numbers _be patient_. Do not reply that the program "seems to crash"; wait until a response appear in the screen. BTW I don't understand what is the purpose of run the program with too many data when 30-50 numbers are enough for testing purposes...

Answer (score 0):

AS aacini mentioned set will order environment vars alphabetically, to have the numbers sorted stuff them with leading zeroes and put the random numbers into the var name, to be able to store the same number multiple times append the index.

**EDIT** Modified the batch to output lists to `unsorted.txt` and `sorted.txt`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "totalNumber=Number of Values:"
set /P "randMax=Max Random Value:"

 echo %date% : %time% PROGRAM INITIATED VALUES:%totalNumber% randMax:%randMax%
(echo %date% : %time% PROGRAM INITIATED VALUES:%totalNumber% randMax:%randMax%) > log.txt

:array
(for /L %%i in (1,1,%totalNumber%) do (
  set /A "Rno=!random! %% randMax + 10*randMax"
  Set a_!Rno!_%%i=0
  Echo:!Rno!
))> unsorted.txt

echo/
 echo %date% : %time% Generated %totalNumber% numbers
(echo %date% : %time% Generated %totalNumber% numbers) >> log.txt

(for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%i in ('set a_') do (
  Set /A No=%%i - 10*randMax,Diff=No-Prev,Prev=No
  Echo:!No!
))> sorted.txt

:complete
 echo %date% : %time% PROGRAM COMPLETE
(echo %date% : %time% PROGRAM COMPLETE) >> log.txt
```

Comment: If you read the question description, the OP is _"interested in computer sorting, and attempted to write a simple batch numerical sorter. It uses very basic math and is extremely inefficient, but was mostly a learning experience"_, but your solution did _not_ provide anyone of these points! A simpler solution would be create a text file with the random numbers and use `sort` command... **`:/`**

Comment: Well, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) my sort method is the very first one, the insertion sort.  ;-)

Comment: Certainly not. The description of insertion sort at the linked Wikipedia article specify: _"It works by taking elements from the list one by one and inserting them in their correct position into a new sorted list... but insertion is expensive, requiring shifting all following elements over by one"_. Please, tell me which part of your code do the expensive insertion via the shifting of following elements, because I can't find it. Your code have not even a single _comparison_ (GTR or LSS), that is a fundamental concept in all [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort)!

Comment: In a way the set inserts into the environment, but obviously you missed the ;-).

Comment: This code seems to work, yet due my low level knowledge of batch, I have no idea how. Also when I enter large values, such as 10,000 for both %totalnumbers% and %randmax%, the program appears to initiate the number generation, then crash, I'm not sure if this is a software fault, or my hardware, or something else.

Comment: @t.anonymous The command line length is limiting when appending all the numbers. I'll do some changes above to output to screen.

Comment: @LotPings this code seems to be working! One of the intended features of the program is to save the unsorted to unsorted.txt and sorted to sorted.txt . You're code is too advanced for me so I do not know how to do that, if you wouldn't mind adding this that would be fantastic.

Comment: @t.anonymous Made requested changes above.